# Pyinstaller не может импортировать модуль

Tags: python, pyinstaller

```
import PIL
```

После сборки через pyinstaller появляется ошибка

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

`--hidden-import = PIL` не помогает, как и `pillow` и `python-pillow`

Скрипт до сборки работает нормально

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете виртуальное окружение, то запускать PyInstaller следует из него.
Если у вас установлено несколько версий Python (2.7, 3.7.7 как вы примере ниже) то запускать PyInstaller следует через ту версию питона, которую вы использовали для создания/компиляции программы.

(Если вы используете Pycharm): 
Т.к. мы используем виртуальное окружение, то открыть консоль и просто написать PyInstaller нельзя. Пользуемся встроенным терминалом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы НЕ используете PyCharm, или аналог, то входите в виртуальное окружение и прописываете 
`python3 -m PyInstaller name.py`

Comment: Обращаю внимание что я писал python3, а не Python, что бы PyInstaller гарантировано работал с 3-ей версией питона, а не со второй.